# Multithreaded construction of large sparse armadillo matrix is slower than single-threaded execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I'm currently writing a piece of code that has to assemble very large matrices in a location-independent way, i.e the value at any location does not depend on the value at any other location. Therefore, I thought that this would be a good thing to parallelize.Here is the logic that I have been following

Partition locations in the matrix based on number of threads (guarantees that there are no race conditions) - then for each thread, allocate some memory for thread local intermediates, matrices ranging from 3x3 to 8x8 to calculate the necessary values.

Then execute the computation to figure out the values to input and assign the values into the sparse armadillo matrix.

Now, the execution is slower than single threaded, and my suspicion is because of the sparse matrix format. What is going on, and are there any ways to actually increase the speed of the matrix construction?

Here is the multithreading code that I use:

```
void PopulateGlobalStiffnessMatrixMultiThreaded(arma::sp_mat* global_stiffness_matrix, Mesh* mesh, Material* material,
                                                int number_of_cpus){
    int step = mesh->elements.n_rows / number_of_cpus;
    int start_element = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_cpus; i++){
        threads.push_back(std::thread(PopulateGlobalStiffnessMatrix, global_stiffness_matrix, mesh, material, start_element, step));
        start_element = start_element + step;
    }

    threads.push_back(std::thread(PopulateGlobalStiffnessMatrix, global_stiffness_matrix, mesh, material, start_element,
                                  mesh->elements.n_rows - start_element - 1));

    for(std::thread &t : threads){
        if (t.joinable()){
            t.join();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To make your program more efficient, design your matrix around the processor's data cache.  Your program should read at least one cache line for the matrix, then operate on that cache line (including reading from and writing to memory).  Reducing the cache reloads will speed up your program.  Also, having the memory sequential will reduce the time to find the next cache line from memory.  This method is independent of threads.

Comment: Threading is not an automatic guarantee to speed up your program.  Worst case scenario the operating system is treating your thread as another task to the same processor (running another task serially).  Also, there is the overhead of starting and maintaining another thread.

Comment: Have you tried parallel processing without launching an additional thread?  There are libraries that can assist in having your processor actually perform executions in parallel.  This may be faster than running a separate thread.

Comment: A sparse matrix is not a data structure known for efficiency, but as space saving. With a normal matrix, accessing a cell is done by math and many processors have specialized instructions for accessing a cell.  A sparse matrix has to go through some decision code, which takes up execution time, thus slowing down performance compared to a normal matrix.  It's a matter of space vs. execution time savings.